# Why doesn't ArrayList class have a newInstance() method?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

Just a theoretical question, shouldn't the method call the empty constructor and thus return an empty list?

Comment: Why doesn't every type have a `newInstance` method? What kind of answer are you looking for here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method `newInstance()` belongs to the class called `Class`. Javadoc:

> Creates a new instance of the class represented by this Class object. The class is instantiated as if by a new expression with an empty argument list.

So these two are equivalent:

```
ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
ArrayList b = ArrayList.class.newInstance();
```

You can do this for every class, but it is not recommended because you lose compile-time safety (it may fail at run-time if there is no no-arg constructor) and cannot track usages.